# Get the two latest major updates (and their latest minor updates) in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, self-updating

I have a table in Redshift which I can access by SQL, and this table gets rows regularly added to it. The updates are both on a monthly interval (major updates) and on a shorter interval (minor updates), kept track of by the `id` column. Suppose this table has three columns, `id`, `val1` and `val2`. The `id` column is something like `NNaaMM`, where:

- `NN` is two digits counting the major updates, starting with `00`, `01`,...
- ­`aa` is two characters indicating the group (which for this question may be considered fixed)
- `MM` is two digits counting the minor updates, starting with `00`, `01`,...

The columns `val1` and `val2` have the information I want to compare. I would like the two most recent large updates, using each of their respective latest minor updates. That is, if the latest large update has `id=54aa12` and the large update before that has `id=53aa02`, then I would like to get a table that looks like the following:

| id | val1 | val2 | which |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54aa12 | foo | 6 | current |
| 54aa12 | bar | 5 | current |
| 53aa02 | foo | 10 | previous |
| 53aa02 | baz | 12 | previous |

So far I have an extremely long and slow query that seems to do the job:

```
WITH prefixes AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(id,1,3) AS prefix  
    FROM table
    WHERE id LIKE '%aa%'
    GROUP BY prefix
    ORDER BY prefix DESC
    LIMIT 2),

id_max AS (
    SELECT t.id AS id
    FROM prefixes 
    JOIN table t
    ON t.id LIKE (SELECT MAX(prefix) FROM prefixes)+'%'
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1),

id_min AS (
    SELECT t.id AS id
    FROM prefixes 
    JOIN table t
    ON t.id LIKE (SELECT MIN(prefix) FROM prefixes)+'%'
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1)

(SELECT *, 'current' AS which
FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM id_max))

UNION ALL

(SELECT *, 'previous' AS which
FROM table
WHERE id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM id_min))
```

My question is: **Is there a better / faster / cleaner way to do this?**

I'm aware everything is working (and so why am I posting here...), but right now it feels like a hack that only I can understand, and this code is part of a bigger project that I have to share with others. So code readability (and shortness if possible) is important, I'm hoping to have something like a single `SELECT .. WHERE id=CURRENT(..) OR id=PREVIOUS(..)`, and I know these functions don't exist, just that format would be preferrable.

Comment: i think you are searching for a window function like row_number

Comment: What is the input data associated with this expected result?

Comment: @Error_2646 There is no input data beyond asking for the two latest updates. This is the first step in a longer sequence, after which the values in the other columns are compared. My expectation is that the result of this query will always be up to date.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis There's gotta be input data, but it sounds like that is just whats in {id, val1, val2} and this whole query is to derive "which"?

Comment: @JānisLazovskis I'm sure there is a nicer way to write this. But just off the bat a simple change is substr(t.id,1,3) = (SELECT MIN(prefix) FROM prefixes) and substr(t.id,1,3) = (SELECT MAX(prefix) FROM prefixes). Because you've already defined prefix to have a length of 3 and joining on LIKE || will almost certainly result in an intermediate product join. Maybe even better to have a CTE with substr(t.id,1,3) added in, then you can equi-join.

Comment: @Error_2646 I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "input data". The other columns are compared in different ways in PowerBI later, and this query that I'm making provides the data for those comparisons. Knowing `which` is important, but in addition I have to retrieve the two tables corresponding to `current` and `previous`.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis Input here would just be the actual content of "table" in your query.

Comment: @Error_2646 Ok I see. I am not sharing more details of the contents of the table because it is sensitive information, but my hope was that this query would work irrespective of the number / types of columns, irrespective of the number of major / minor updates, irrespective of the group being considered, and irrespective of the number of rows in each update. I used your answer to get there.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis Appreciate it, in the future it doesn't have to be the exact data. Most folks aren't too keen on sharing their company's exact data. Just representative of the scenarios that the logic should handle. So "123-Apple" is just as good as an actual loan number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are more cases than your sample data covers, but row_number() can be used here.

Rationale - Partition by all the records which have minor updates, of those row_number() ordered by the first three characters will give you 1 & 2 for your latest two and >2 for everything else.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    id VARCHAR(50),
    val1 VARCHAR(50),
    val2 INT,
    which VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, val1, val2, which) VALUES ('54aa12', 'foo', 6, 'current');
INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, val1, val2, which) VALUES ('54aa12', 'bar', 5, 'current');
INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, val1, val2, which) VALUES ('53aa02', 'foo', 10, 'previous');
INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, val1, val2, which) VALUES ('53aa02', 'baz', 12, 'previous');

select *,
       case when 
           row_number() over ( 
             partition by id like '%aa%'
                 order by substr(id, 1, 3) desc
             ) <= 2 
           then 'current' 
           else 'previous'
       end as derived_which
  from your_table_name;
```

| id | val1 | val2 | which | derived_which |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54aa12 | foo | 6 | current | current |
| 54aa12 | bar | 5 | current | current |
| 53aa02 | foo | 10 | previous | previous |
| 53aa02 | baz | 12 | previous | previous |

Comment: This is clean because it does not use common table expressions, but it does not work because the `aa` characters are different in my setting. I'm still accepting this answer, because I modified it into a common table expression as `WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS rn FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%aa%' ORDER BY rn ASC, id DESC LIMIT 2)`, then used `(SELECT *, 'current' AS which FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cte) UNION ALL (SELECT *, 'previous' AS which FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM cte)` to get the right parts of the table.

Comment: For posterity, the working CTE is actually `SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(id,1,3) ORDER BY SUBSTRING(id,1,3) DESC) AS rn FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%aa%' GROUP BY id ORDER BY rn ASC, id DESC LIMIT 2`.